# How do I make table cells smaller in a Material UI table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and ReactJS. This is the first time I use Material UI and react and I am having difficulties solving my problem. I want to make my cells smaller. But, the code which set `width` and `height` is not working. It seems there are minimum `width` and `height` options set in the element and it doesn't go smaller when I override them with `makeStyles` code. I also tried to change `minHeight` and `minWidth` by code and work in sass file, but it is not working either.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    minHeight: 0
  },
  table: {},
  row: {
    height: 10
  },
  cell: {
    fontSize: "10px",
    height: 10,
    minHeight: 5,
    width: 10,
    minWidth: 10
  }
}));

export default function TimeTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead className={classes.head}>
          <TableRow className={classes.row}>
            <TableCell></TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.cell}>월</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.cell}>화</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.cell}>수</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.cell}>목</TableCell>
            <TableCell className={classes.cell}>금</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row, i) => (
            <TableRow>
              {i % 2 === 0 && (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} key={i} rowSpan="2">
                  {9 + Math.floor(i / 2)}
                </TableCell>
              )}
              {row.Monday === "" ? (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} />
              ) : (
                i % row.Monday.slice(0, 1) === 0 && (
                  <TableCell
                    className={classes.cell}
                    rowSpan={row.Monday.slice(0, 1)}
                  >
                    {row.Monday.slice(2)}
                  </TableCell>
                )
              )}
              {row.Tuesday === "" ? (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} />
              ) : (
                i % row.Tuesday.slice(0, 1) === 0 && (
                  <TableCell
                    className={classes.cell}
                    rowSpan={row.Tuesday.slice(0, 1)}
                  >
                    {row.Tuesday.slice(2)}
                  </TableCell>
                )
              )}
              {row.Wednesday === "" ? (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} />
              ) : (
                i % row.Wednesday.slice(0, 1) === 0 && (
                  <TableCell
                    className={classes.cell}
                    rowSpan={row.Wednesday.slice(0, 1)}
                  >
                    {row.Wednesday.slice(2)}
                  </TableCell>
                )
              )}
              {row.Thursday === "" ? (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} />
              ) : (
                i % row.Thursday.slice(0, 1) === 0 && (
                  <TableCell
                    className={classes.cell}
                    rowSpan={row.Thursday.slice(0, 1)}
                  >
                    {row.Thursday.slice(2)}
                  </TableCell>
                )
              )}
              {row.Friday === "" ? (
                <TableCell className={classes.cell} />
              ) : (
                i % row.Friday.slice(0, 1) === 0 && (
                  <TableCell
                    className={classes.cell}
                    rowSpan={row.Friday.slice(0, 1)}
                  >
                    {row.Friday.slice(2)}
                  </TableCell>
                )
              )}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

`Page(className: root)` width and height are well applied as you can see lines across the table. But, the `table` and `cell` width and height are not applied. I want to fit my table into the `Page(className: root)`.

Comment: There are some things you should modify for us to be able to help you. First, create a ["Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your problem. Include this `Page` component you mention and try to frame your question a little better. Try to show an example of what should happened, and what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

@guzmonne -- 
Here is mimimum reproducible example. [image: Edit material-ui-table-cell-width]

In the code - total Row width is 700 px. The long Cell should have 600 px width and short cell should have 100px width. But it is not the case.